# use htaccess or PHP for url rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, zend-framework

I got some links in my website like this : monsite/page.html/something.html
what I want is to change these url to look like this : monsite/page/something.html Or monsite/page/something

I don't know if I can do that using .htaccess or do I have to look for a solution using PHP (i am using Zend framework)

So if I choose to use .htaccess , here is the line that added but I Keep getting 404 error : 
RewriteRule ^([-a-zA-Z]+)/page/([-a-zA-Z0-9]+).html$ $1/page.html/$2.html

Comment: There is no difference in what you have and what you want.

Comment: I am sorry , I edited my post

Comment: After reading the post, I guess in my case it s better to use htaccess,  but the issue I always get 404 error, I edited my post with htaccess code